# How to store data in one table with distinct attributes in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Need a little help with Laravel 8, I have two users with the same attributes but the other one has another attribute :

**Seeker: name, email, password**

**Agent: name, email, password, broker license no**

This is my form:
[image: register like Seeker]

[image: register like Agent]

If the user registers as an agent, other fields require only for an agent.
I'm having trouble on how to store it in a database.

```
protected function create(array $data) 
{ 
  $r_id = isset($data['agent']) ? 2 : 3; 
    return User::create([    
      'given_name' => $data['given_name'], 
      'last_name' => $data['last_name'], 
      'email' => $data['email'], 
      'password' => Hash::make($data['password']), 
      'role_id' => $r_id, ]); 
}
```

Comment: you can add another table as said in the answer below, you can keep unicity via code (not recommended) or you can save two different entities: even if they share almost all the fields, it might be better to seperate them in two table if they have different relations with other tables in your database. in all cases, your question is opinion based. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create another table for information agents and use [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) with column `id` in table `users`

[image]

Sample code :

```
   $user =  User::create([    
          'given_name' => $data['given_name'], 
          'last_name' => $data['last_name'], 
          'email' => $data['email'], 
          'password' => Hash::make($data['password']), 
          'role_id' => $r_id
    ]);

  if($r_id === 2){
    
    Agent::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    .
    .
    ...
    ]);

  }
```

User relation to Agent :

```
public function agent()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Agent::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```